# Accessing static file in views.py

Tags: python

I have a joblib file containing a trained scikit-learn model that I need to access and load in my `views.py`.

My `settings.py` looks like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I have a `static` folder located in an app called `usersession`, that in turn contains two subfolders: `css` and `scikit`. The former is accessed in templates via `"{% static 'css/styles.css' %}"`.

The `views.py` in question is located in the same app (`usersessions`).

Given that, I thought I would be able to load the model as follows:

```
from joblib import load
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static

softmax_reg = load(static('scikit/softmax_reg.joblib'))
```

But that gives me the following error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'static/scikit/softmax_reg.joblib'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: may be you should use "./static/" not "/static/"

Comment: Where? In the settings or the views file? Not the former, since the css is working. And the latter uses `static('scikit/softmax_reg.joblib')`. So what do you have in mind?

Comment: in settings.py like STATIC_URL = 'static/'

Comment: Didn't work - all it did was have the template lose track of the CSS. What's weird is that I can't even access the file when hardcoding the local address (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/scikit/softmax_reg.joblib), even though actually putting that address in the browser downloads the file.